# Library search path for libstdc++

Tags: dynamic, linker, libstdc++

I have compiled shared libraries dynamically linked against libstdc++.so using GLIBCXX_3.4.11. I want to send my code to someone whose stdc++ library is only of version 3.4.10. Rather than ask him to update his library version (this is a software customer, so I can't assume they'll be willing or able to change system files) I would like to ship the appropriate version of libstdc++.so, placed in a lib folder with the directory location of my code. How do I get my own code to use the appropriate (later) version? I find that /etc/ld.so.conf includes the directory /lib64, where an offending older version of libstdc++.so resides. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not override this. This seems to deviate from the [advertised](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) behavior. Any idea why this is happening? How do I complete my rather simple task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that this question is old, but I found it while trying to sort out my own linking trouble which was similar. You will have to build your program against a version of libstdc++ which is compatible with your colleague's version of the library. The easiest solution, of course, is to link against his version of the library so he doesn't need to make special tweaks on his side to link your library.

To do this, you will want to install a version of GCC which can build binary compatible libraries so you can actually link against his version of libstdc++.  GLIBCXX_3.4.11 is from gcc-4.4 and later, so you will need gcc-4.3. Build your program using this and you should be in good shape.

You can consult the following page for a list of library ABI compatabilities:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

You could also build an rpm/deb which requires the version of libstdc++ you already have and if it's not available, refuse to install. This gives you a bit of an interface which gives him a promise that if his system is setup with the correct dependencies, he can use your library. In that sense, it's like a loose SLA for your library in what you do and don't support.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just realized that my answer is dumb and you should just use the `-static` flag so you don't need to manage any library versions when deploying to your colleague's computer.